# How to Perform Arithmetic Operations in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

How can I do this in sequelize?

```
SELECT ProductID, Name, ListPrice, ListPrice * 1.15 AS NewPrice  
FROM Production
```

I've tried:

```
db.Production.findAndCountAll(
    attributes: {
        include: [
            ['ListPrice * 1.15', 'NewPrice']
        ]
    }
).then(function(orders){
    return res.jsonp(output);
})
```

But it doesn't work.

This is the query that I expect:

```
SELECT Production.ProductID, Production.Name, Production.ListPrice, Production.ListPrice * 1.15 AS NewPrice  
FROM Production
```

Instead, I see this query:

```
SELECT Production.ProductID, Production.Name, Production.ListPrice, ListPrice * 1.15 AS NewPrice  
FROM Production
```

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: yeah bro. already hand that project to my client. I end up, wrote a raw query for that one. I'm wondering if I do this might work: ['Production.ListPrice * 1.15', 'NewPrice']. You can try as now i'm busy on another project.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Sequelize.literal](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-literal) method. Here is the code:

```
db.Production.findAndCountAll(
    attributes: [
        [Sequelize.literal('ListPrice * 1.15'), 'NewPrice'],
    ]
).then(function(orders){
    return res.jsonp(output);
})
```